# Android:Sort list by date

Tags: android, listview

I am new to android. I am working on a project. I have a list view with date in it.I have to sort the list items by showing recent dates first and the dates that has expired last.
I tried the following code but not getting the results

```
        public static String getDate(long milliSeconds, String dateFormat)
        throws Exception {
    DateFormat formatter = null;
    Calendar calendar = null;
    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
     Date date = new Date(0);
        String current_date = formatter.format(date);

    try {

        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

    Collections.sort(null, new Comparator<MyObject>() {
          public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
              if (o1.getDateTime() == null || o2.getDateTime() == null)
                return 0;
              return o1.getDateTime().compareTo(o2.getDateTime());
          }
        });



    return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());

   }
}
```

please help with some code . I dont know how to code using comparator. My listview object is lv. where should i write the code and declare the listview.Please help with some code.

My adapter for class is as follows

```
   public class Test_List_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

public Activity context;
public String names[];
public String endDate[];
public String questions[];
public LayoutInflater inflater;

public Test_List_Adapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String> testid,
        ArrayList<String> testName, ArrayList<String> endDate,
        ArrayList<String> questions) {
    this.context = context;
    this.names = testName.toArray(new String[0]);
    this.endDate = endDate.toArray(new String[0]);
    this.questions = questions.toArray(new String[0]);
//  this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)                                                          context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return names.length;
}

   @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return null;
    }

    @Override
      public long getItemId(int arg0) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
     }

public static class ViewHolder {
    TextView testname;
    TextView questions;
    TextView testenddate;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    try {

        ViewHolder holder;
        //Test_List_Adapter.setSelectedIndex(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            //inflater = (LayoutInflater)                                          context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                      //inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_list_items,
                    null);
            holder.testname = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.testName);
            holder.questions = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.noofQuestions);
            holder.testenddate = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.testDate);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        holder.testname.setText(names[position]);
        holder.testenddate.setText(endDate[position]);
        holder.questions.setText(questions[position]);
        Log.v("exiting =test list adapter", "true");
        Log.v("exiting =test list adapter", "return convertview");
        notifyDataSetChanged();     
        } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Test_List_Adapter/getView()", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
            return convertView;
        }
           }
```

Comment: You're sorting in the wrong place. Next to that, you are passing null to the Collections.sort() while that should be a collection of items you want to sort. Can you show the code where you create the adapter for the list?

Comment: I edited my adapter class.

Comment: Can you show the lines where you create the adapter, and the lines where you retrieve your enddates?